# Unix: How to replace a pattern with every string from another file

Tags: shell, unix, command-line

I have file named `fileA` , containing

```
comA comB comC
```

then another file named `fileB` , containing

```
for bp in `pgrep REPLACE_IT`;
do
echo 1 > /proc/REPLACE_IT/oom_adj
echo 1 > /proc/$bp/oom_score_adj
done 2>/dev/null
```

How to substitute every word `REPLACE_IT` in `fileB` with every word in `fileA` , then print result to `fileC`?

Desired output in `fileC`:

```
for bp in `pgrep comA`;
do
echo 1 > /proc/comA/oom_adj
echo 1 > /proc/$bp/oom_score_adj
done 2>/dev/null
for bp in `pgrep comB`;
do
echo 1 > /proc/comB/oom_adj
echo 1 > /proc/$bp/oom_score_adj
done 2>/dev/null
for bp in `pgrep comC`;
do
echo 1 > /proc/comC/oom_adj
echo 1 > /proc/$bp/oom_score_adj
done 2>/dev/null
```

Thanks for any advice

Answer (score 0):

would something like that do the trick ?

```
for i in $(cat fileA); do
    sed 's|REPLACE_IT|'$i'|g' <fileB >temp
    cat temp >> fileC
done
```

Comment: Your trick almost near my goal, I only slightly adjust to my purpose. You save my day